# PHP Force Download Remote File without Going Through Our Server

Tags: php, file, download

I wrote a php script which retrieves flv URL from YouTube and force download it using header and readfile() function. It works properly but the flv file goes through my hosting server before going to the user that spend tons of bandwidth and cause the server down.

Does anyone have the better solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: What you might be looking for is a so called redirect. However, after redirecting, your users browser decides how to handle the new URL, e.g. open it inside a plugin for example.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. develop a browser plugin that forces a download and/or saves the file to disk directly
2. tell the user to "right-click and choose *Save As...*"

You cannot force another server to do something or a client to interact with a server in any specific way.

Answer (score 0):

If you offer it with readfile, it necessarily has to go through your server. the only thing you could do is to redirect to the flv directly. or they have to "save as" to get the file.

the thing you could do to optimize the process is to cache the file on your server. this would use your bandwidth too, but you wouldn't have to grab the file from youtube all the time.